# 1D Smoluchowski diffusion equation in a linear potential

Tags: differentiation, diffusion

I am interested in solving a 1D Smoluchowski diffusion equation in a linear potential $U(x) = cx$ for a constant force $c$. This problem follows chapter 4 of the theoretical biophysics script by Schulten.

The Smoluchowski equation reads
\begin{equation}
\partial_t p(x,t|x_0,t_0) = \left(D \partial_x^2 + D\beta c \partial_x \right)p(x,t|x_0,t_0)
\end{equation}
They use the initial condition
\begin{equation}
p(x,t_0|x_0,t_0) = \delta(x-x_0)
\end{equation}

In order to solve the equation they first introduce $\tau = Dt$ and $b=\beta c$ which allows to rewrite the equation in the form
\begin{equation}
\partial_\tau p(x,\tau|x_0,\tau_0) = \left( \partial_x^2 + b \partial_x \right)p(x,\tau|x_0,\tau_0)
\end{equation}

Up to this point I have no trouble following what is going on. But in the next step they introduce time dependent spatial coordinates by using
\begin{equation}
y = x+b\tau \qquad , \quad y_0 = x_0 + b\tau_0
\end{equation}
and express the solution as
\begin{equation}
p(x,\tau|x_0,\tau_0) = q(y,\tau|y_0,\tau_0)
\end{equation}
The differential equation for $q$ then takes the form:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\tau}q(y,\tau|y_0,\tau_0) + b \partial_y q(y,\tau|y_0,\tau_0) = (\partial_y^2 + b\partial_y ) q(y,\tau|y_0,\tau_0)
\end{equation}

How does on thoroughly explain the second term on the left hand side?
I understand, that this is some kind of chain rule, that stems from the substitution that has been made, but I am confused, since the two independent coordinates $x$ and $\tau$ get coupled by $y$. 
I do understand that this step is a nice trick here, since it transforms the problem into the equation for free diffusion, but I would like to know how I derive the left hand side of this equation.

For a generic function $f(x,t)$ this would mean, that
\begin{equation}
\partial_t f(x,t) = \partial_tg(y,t) + \partial_yg(y,t)\cdot \partial_t y
\end{equation}
Is this what is happening here?
Thanks for any kind of help.
Best regards,
khx0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the chain rule for derivatives, that is, for instance : 
$$\partial_t \,g(y_1(x, t), y_2(x, t)) = \partial_{y_1} \,g(y_1(x, t), y_2(x, t)) \,\partial_t y_1(x, t) + \partial_{y_2} \,g(y_1(x, t), y_2(x, t)) \,\partial_t y_2(x, t) $$

Now, you may apply it with $y_1(x,t)= x+bt$ and $y_2(x,t)= t$, and you will recover your formula.

Comment: You are right. I think the fact of $y_2(x,t)=t$ plainly being $t$ distracted me from that is is actually no more than the normal chain rule.